# Vimeo PHP Upload Directory

Tags: php, api, oauth, vimeo

I have spent this best part of a week rattling my brain to get this working and I've just come to the conclusion that this is out of my scope. I know this is a rather large ask but I just can't figure it out. :(

Anyway, I am trying to upload some files in a directory on my webserver to Vimeo through a protected php script (I say protected because the script itself will not be accessible from the web) and have that script run via a cron job. The script will only upload to my account.

I have gotten as far as getting a consumer key and consumer secret from vimeo.

I have been attempting to use their documented API demo but that keeps requesting an oauth_token and oauth_token_secret, both of which I don't know how to obtain. I found it quite confusing and unsure if I could adapt it for my requirements. Instead, I googled and found this blog post about transfering files from youtube to vimeo - http://mclear.co.uk/2011/05/27/transfer-videos-from-youtube-to-vimeo/ - I thought I could use it as a building block but I've hit a dead end here also.

To explain the full scale of what I'm trying to achieve:

**Video file is created on originating computer - Working**

**User adds ID3 tags to the file and drops it in a watched folder - Working**

**Local server sends the file via ftp to the webserver directory - Working**

**Php script reads the ID3 for the file and uploads it to vimeo - [ID3 Extractor working -Vimeo uploader not working]**

**Vimeo responds with upload location to script which then connects to our mysql server to add the record - Not working but straightforward to implement once uploader works**

Thank you so much in advance for any help you can give.
Richard

Comment: So, your problem is how to obtain the Oauth token?

Comment: Hi deceze. My problem is broader than that my friend. I just don't understand how to implement what I want to achieve :-( I know I will need an oauth token though - care to shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I made some progress on this with the php "Transfer Youtube to Vimeo tool" I made](http://mclear.co.uk/2011/05/27/transfer-videos-from-youtube-to-vimeo/)

The download at the bottom of the article will get you uploading w/ PHP

The CLI tool is now available and comes with a video tutorial for how to use it.

Credit to @TomNomNom

Please don't contact me RE this I'm not supporting this code it was just hacked together :)