# How to upload videos to Vimeo programmatically in PHP?

Tags: php, video, vimeo

I have a an input for uploading videos on my site. The videos get uploaded on my server and then it is presented via `video` tag. But as you can imagine, the user uploads only one video with one extension (e.g. mp4), in that case I can't use that video in all the browsers. So, maybe what I could do is upload the same video to vimeo (via their api) and then host this video via "iframe code" or something. My question is: Is it even possible? And is it a good idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vimeo PHP Upload Directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027289/vimeo-php-upload-directory)

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible, you can and should use the Vimeo API: https://developer.vimeo.com/api

Also it is pretty a good idea, because Vimeo is suited to transcoding and serving millions of videos every day and by definition is way more stable than your own video service. Unless you are facing the legal requirement to host the video on your own server, it is probably better to use external CDN (like Vimeo) for it.

But you will have to use cURL or some other HTTP requests library to access the functions and perform tasks. Check it out here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Have you used it before? Can I also limit access for specific users afterwards?

Comment: I have used YouTube as CDN a lot, and Vimeo is basically the same thing. Regarding the access restrictions - yes, there are options for it in Vimeo Pro: https://vimeo.com/forums/topic:44387 With basic Vimeo all your videos are accessible via link.